# Custom directive scss

Tags: sass, tailwind-css

Tailwind has his custom directive `@tailwind` to import styles and components.

Is there any way to create custom directives in scss?

I was watching for something like `@custom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be any public API offered by Sass to add custom at-rule directives. The `@tailwind` directive is something that is parsed and replaced by the Tailwind PostCSS plugin *after* Sass has run its own compilation. So as a compromise, you could try implementing a PostCSS plugin instead that parses and "compiles" a custom `@custom` directive.